# Producer-consumer synchronization problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer, autoresetevent

I'm trying to write a simple producer-consumer app where I need to read data in chunks from a file (which may be huge) and (for simple testing purposes) just write them to another file through another thread.

I've tried to follow lots of online sources but these thread synchronization tasks are difficult for me to understand and each of the examples I have found missed some important aspects for me.

**I have put together pieces of code which ALMOST seem to work** but there is something threads-related which is obviously wrong so I wanted to ask you for help if anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong.
**If I run the program below for some test file the program finishes OK** (at least for me and my test file) but **if I uncomment `Thread.Sleep(20)` in the `dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile` method** (in order to test what happens when the producer is faster then the consumer) then (based on the data printed in the console) the producer inserts maxQueueSize+1 data blocks in the queue and **the program gets into some infinite loop or something**.

I suspect **`_producerThreadWaitEventHandler.Set()`** call might be a part of a problem because at the moment **it is called in `dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile` for every single while loop** (I'd like to call it only if necessary, i.e. if the **`_producerThreadWaitEventHandler.waitOne()`** has been called and I should wake that thread, but **I don't know how to find out whether for a particular thread waitOne has been called or not in order to wake the thread**).
There may be other synchronization problems, of course, but as I'm new to multithreading I don't know where to look first and what would be the best solution.

Note, I want to use (and understand) basic techniques (such as **Monitor** or **AutoResetEvent**) for synchronization (instead of BlockingQueue, TPL etc.) so I hope some minor tweaks to the code below would make it work.

I'll be grateful for any hint.

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class ProducerConsumerApp : IDisposable
{
public static string originalFilePath = @"D:\test.txt";
public static string outputFilePath = @"D:\test_export.txt";
public static int blockSize = 15;

int maxQueueSize = 4;  // max allowed number of objects in the queue

EventWaitHandle _consumerThreadWaitEventHandler = new AutoResetEvent(false);
EventWaitHandle _producerThreadWaitEventHandler = new AutoResetEvent(false);

Thread _consumerThread;
readonly object _lock = new object();
Queue<byte[]> _queue = new Queue<byte[]>();

public ProducerConsumerApp(Stream outputStream)
{
    _consumerThread = new Thread(dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile);
    _consumerThread.Start(outputStream);
}

public void enqueueObject(byte[] data)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        // TODO !!!
        // Make sure producent doesn't enqueue more objects than the maxQueueSize is,
        // i.e. let the producent wait until consumer dequeues some object from the full queue
        if (_queue.Count > maxQueueSize)     // would "while" be better? Doesn't seem to change anything
        {
            _producerThreadWaitEventHandler.WaitOne();
        }
        // Thread.Sleep(20); // just for testing

        _queue.Enqueue(data);

        // data being read in case of a text file:
        //string str = (data==null) ? "<null>" : System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
        //Console.WriteLine("Enqueuing data: "+str);

    }
    _consumerThreadWaitEventHandler.Set();  // data enqueued  => wake the consumerThread
}

public void Dispose()  // called automatically (IDisposable implementer) when instance is being destroyed
{
    enqueueObject(null);                         // Signal the consumer to exit.
    _consumerThread.Join();                     // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
    _consumerThreadWaitEventHandler.Close();    // Release any OS resources.
}

void dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile(object outputStream)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Thread.Sleep(20); // slow down the consumerThread to check what happens when the producer fully fills the queue
        // PROBLEM - the app gets into some infinite loop if I do this!!! What exactly is wrong?

        byte[] data = null;
        lock (_lock)
            if (_queue.Count > 0)   // queue not empty
            {
                data = _queue.Dequeue();

                _producerThreadWaitEventHandler.Set();
                // !!! This doesn't seem right - I don't want to call this in each while iteration
                // I would like to call it only if _producerThreadWaitEventHandler.WaitOne has been called 
                // but how to check such a condition?

                if (data == null) 
                {                  
                    // Console.WriteLine("Data file reading finished => let consumerThread finish and then quit the app");
                    return;                
                }
            }
        if (data != null)
        {
            ((FileStream)outputStream).Write(data, 0, data.Length); // write data from the queue to a file

            // just a test in case of a text file:
            // string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
            // Console.WriteLine("Data block retrieved from the queue and written to a file: " + str);

        } else {   // empty queue => let the consumerThread wait
            _consumerThreadWaitEventHandler.WaitOne();  // No more tasks - wait for a signal
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{

    FileInfo originalFile = new FileInfo(originalFilePath);
    byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];
    int bytesRead;

    using (FileStream originalFileStream = originalFile.OpenRead())    // file input stream
    using (FileStream fileOutputStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (ProducerConsumerApp q = new ProducerConsumerApp(fileOutputStream))
    {
        while ((bytesRead = originalFileStream.Read(data, 0, blockSize)) > 0)   // reads blocks of data from a file
        {
            // test - in case of a text file:
            //string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
            //Console.WriteLine("data block read from a file:" + str);

            if (bytesRead < data.Length)
            {
                byte[] data2 = new byte[bytesRead];
                Array.Copy(data, data2, bytesRead);
                data = data2;
            }

            q.enqueueObject(data);   // put the data into the queue

            data = new byte[blockSize];
        }
    }
    // because of "using" the Dispose method is going to be called in the end which will call enqueueObject(null) resulting in stopping the consumer thread

    Console.WriteLine("Finish");
}
}
```

Comment: Your `dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile` thread is waiting for the lock which is set by the other thread, which in return waits for the first thread's `_producerThreadWaitEventHandler.Set();` . So basically you have a race condition: both threads waiting for each other and nothing happening. When the `dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile` thread runs first (no sleeping), it can access the lock. But since it can't (because sleeping means the other thread locks first), you are stuck.

Comment: If you need a thread safe queue. Use [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1). Unless you stuck on .Net 2.0

Comment: You may find this interesting: [How to process data from a file in parallel in several threads and write them into another file while keeping the original data order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403335/how-to-process-data-from-a-file-in-parallel-in-several-threads-and-write-them-in/60425467?noredirect=1#comment106903976_60425467). There are higher level tools for this job than the `Monitor` and `AutoResetEvent` synchronization primitives.

Comment: @Chronicle You're right! Thanks you very much for clarification. I replaced event handler's WaitOne a Set methods with Monitor.Wait (which releases the lock so the other thread can run) and Monitor.Pulse and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you wait in a lock.  This means that the other thread will also block on the lock statement and never call `_producerThreadWaitEventHandler.Set();`  Classical deadlock.

You better use a [Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.8)  to limit the number of items the produce can put in the queue.
Initialize the semaphore as all free: `producerSemaphore = new Semaphore (15, 15);`.  In the producer, Wait on the semaphore, and in the consumer - call `Release()`.

In the same fashion, you can use a Semaphore or a [CountdownEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?view=netframework-4.8) to avoid relying on `queue.Count`.

Even better, you can use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8) in combination with the semaphore to make sure the producer doesn't overfill the queue.
If you successfully dequeue an item from the queue, call `producerSemaphore.Release();`.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a lot simpler if you use a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead.  EG

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

class ProducerConsumerApp : IDisposable
{
    public static int blockSize = 15;

    const int maxQueueSize = 4;  // max allowed number of objects in the queue

    BlockingCollection<byte[]> _queue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>(maxQueueSize);
    private Thread _consumerThread;

    public ProducerConsumerApp(Stream outputStream)
    {
        _consumerThread = new Thread(dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile);
        _consumerThread.Start(outputStream);
    }

    public void enqueueObject(byte[] data)
    {
        _queue.Add(data);
    }

    public void Dispose()  // called automatically (IDisposable implementer) when instance is being destroyed
    {
        enqueueObject(null);                         // Signal the consumer to exit.
        _consumerThread.Join();                     // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
    }

    void dequeueObjectAndWriteItToFile(object outputStream)
    {
        var outStream = (FileStream)outputStream;
        while (true)
        {
            var data = _queue.Take();
            if (data == null)
            {
                outStream.Close();
                // Console.WriteLine("Data file reading finished => let consumerThread finish and then quit the app");
                return;
            }
            outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); // write data from the queue to a file
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var originalFilePath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        var outputFilePath = @"c:\temp\test_out.txt";

        FileInfo originalFile = new FileInfo(originalFilePath);
        byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];
        int bytesRead;

        using (FileStream originalFileStream = originalFile.OpenRead())    // file input stream
        using (FileStream fileOutputStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (ProducerConsumerApp q = new ProducerConsumerApp(fileOutputStream))
        {
            while ((bytesRead = originalFileStream.Read(data, 0, blockSize)) > 0)   // reads blocks of data from a file
            {
                // test - in case of a text file:
                //string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                //Console.WriteLine("data block read from a file:" + str);

                if (bytesRead < data.Length)
                {
                    byte[] data2 = new byte[bytesRead];
                    Array.Copy(data, data2, bytesRead);
                    data = data2;
                }

                q.enqueueObject(data);   // put the data into the queue

                data = new byte[blockSize];
            }
        }
        // because of "using" the Dispose method is going to be called in the end which will call enqueueObject(null) resulting in stopping the consumer thread

        Console.WriteLine("Finish");
    }
}
```